# How can I make the clear trails left behind by water droplets?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

How can I make the clear trails left behind by water droplets that go downwards of a glass surface, like you can see in the picture below.

[image]

[image]

I have added my node setup to make it clear, if it's not clear or hard to see, it's the exact same nodesetup for glass as shown on the website Chocofur (only their glass is orange)

Comment: I mean the clear trails (I forgot to write trails)

Comment: If you need to edit your question or add extra details you can use the [edit] link below it. I also think it would help if you showed the result of your current node setup. It's hard to see what you still need to do if we can't see what you've got.

Comment: Have a look at [Dynamic paint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/dynamic_paint/introduction.html) or use an image to control the mix factor.

Comment: Boundless Blending has a procedural rainy window texture that you can download and study http://boundlessblending.com/blender-cycles-materials/ - also Blender Guru has a tutorial on creating this effect   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO8kw0a2ZeI